# Entering a random number sequence seed under surveillance

Tags: encryption, password-protection, spyware, internet-security, random-number-generator

I'm trying to transmit a continuous sequence of random numbers from my computer over to another country (for validation purpose). This sequence is a series of pseudo random numbers recursively generated from a seed. Now imagine the local government agency is trying to hack my computer to decipher my sequence so they can replicate and transmit their own version while cutting off my stream. To prevent this I need to make sure the seed is not known to them. This is difficult because assume my computer is being totally bugged and monitored. How to enter the seed into the computer without them finding out?

Answer (score 2):

> How to enter the seed into the computer without them finding out?

You cannot.

> assume my computer is being totally bugged and monitored

The above statement means anything that happens on your computer is potentially observable by a 3rd party.  A compromised computer is no longer secure.